# multiple user/thread logins with different inputs in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created a test plan for creating userprofile. 
I want to run my test plan for 100 users but when i run it for 10 users then it is running successfully with `rump up` time of `2 sec`;  but when i try it for 100 users & more than that it is getting failed I am giving `rump uptime` of `40 sec` for 100 users.
I am not able to understand what may be the problem with it.

In my test plan the thread user are differentiated with id

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wide question, this behavior can be caused by

1. Your application under test can't handle load of 100 threads. Check logs for errors and make sure that application/web server and/or database configuration allow 100+ concurrent connections. Also you can check "[Latency](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html#glossary)" metric to see if there is a problem with infrastructure or application itself.
2. Your load generator machine can't create 100 concurrent threads. If so - you'll need to consider JMeter [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
3. Your script isn't optimized. I.e. using memory-consuming listeners like "View Results Tree", any graph listeners, regular expression extractors. Try following [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) and see whether it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dmitri, reason could be one of the above three.

One more thing you can try.

You can run your jmeter in ui mode for validation of your script and after validation you can run it in non-ui mode which will save lot of memory and cpu processing (basically UI is heaviest part in jmeter).

you can run your jmeter script in non-ui mode like this,

Jmeter -n -t  -H proxy -P port

generally on a single dual core machine with 2 GB ram  (Load Generator in your case) 100 user test can be carried out successfully.

some more things you can look at to find out the actual bottleneck

1.check application server logs (server on which your application is hosted)

if there are any failures in that then see performance counters on server (CPU, Memory, network etc) to see anything is overloaded.
(if server is windows then check using perfmon if linux then try sar)
if something is overloaded then reason is your app server cant take load of 100 users 
probably try tuning it more.

2.check load generator system performance counters (JVM heap usage,CPU,Memory etc)

if JVM heap size is small enough try increasing it but if other counters are overloaded then try distributed load testing.

3.remove unwanted/heavy listeners, assertion from script.

maybe this will help :)